# How to change the prezto and zsh theme prompt?

Tags: zsh, prompt, prezto

I installed yadr and prezto to style the zsh prompt.

I'm using the **steeef** theme:
https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_steeef_setup

How do I change the format of the prompt:

from --> `taciano at asimov in`

to --> `taciano@asimov`

I've tried to modify and I couldn't. I can't find where to make this adjustment.

Comment: Either set `PS1` to a different value or edit the prompt definition directly, see `info zsh "prompt themes"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the `steef` theme as the basis for a new theme, say, `taciano`:

   ```bsh
   % cd $ZPREZTODIR/modules/prompt/functions
   % cp prompt_steeef_setup prompt_taciano_setup
   ```
2. In your `.zpreztorc` file, find

   ```bsh
   zstyle ':prezto:module:prompt' theme <value>
   ```

   and change `<value>` to `taciano`.
3. In the file `$ZPREZTODIR/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_taciano_setup`, change [the line that sets the `PROMPT` variable](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/0a405494cae54e208ff550c1ba83380ed115410a/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_steeef_setup#L94).
4. Restart your shell.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was in not having checked the line to set the PROMPT variable. Now it worked!

Still, I find these scripts pretty confusing.

Comment: Well, at least you know where to post any questions you might have. ;)

Comment: @TacianoMoraisSilva So, can you accept my answer, then?